# Extract average column in a list (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

| Name | Measure 1 | Measure 2 | Measure 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| Name1 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 |
| Name1 | 0.6 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| Name1 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
| Name2 | 0.5 | 0.8 | 0.3 |
| Name2 | 0.1 | 0.6 | 0.4 |
| Name2 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.8 |
| Name2 | 0.9 | 0.1 | 0.6 |
| Name3 | 0.8 | 0.2 | 0.9 |
| Name3 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.2 |
| Name3 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| Name3 | 0.7 | 0.6 | 0.7 |

And I would like to extract the mean of each column and get this:

- Name1 = [Mean Measure1, Mean Measure2, Mean Measure3]
- Name2 = [Mean Measure1, Mean Measure2, Mean Measure3]
- Name3 = [Mean Measure1, Mean Measure2, Mean Measure3]

What would be the best way to obtain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think you should first look for *a* way yourself, share your attempts & where it fails (if it does), and only then look for "the best way".

Comment: Looks like you want a simple `df.groupby('Name').mean()`